# Passing native method as callback in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

Is it possible to pass a native method as a callback argument when writing native components in React Native?

I tried something like this, but the argument is undefined in the callback in the JavaScript code:

```
- (void) complete {
    NSLog(@"completing");
}

RCTResponseSenderBlock callbackComp = complete;
callback(@[[NSNull null], callbackComp]);
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Never tried something like this but I have an idea. What you can do is to create and export the callback you want to fire with `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` and then you can combine all your callback implementations in a single file. Then you can pass the name of the exact callback you need to fire for that method. Then in Javascript something like this should work I think. `CallbackManager['nameOfYourCallbakMethodFromMethod']()`

Answer (score 0):

below link should be helpful,
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html